# Unknown ERROR in my system(14.04)

Tags: 14.04, update-manager, error-handling

I am using 14.04 for last few months, now it's showing an unknown error in the notification area, as shown in the below Image...

[image: error]

When I click there am getting message as,

*The updated information is outdated. This may be cause by network problems or by a repository that is no longer available. Please update manually by selecting "Show updates" from indicator menu, and watching for failing repositories.*

But when I click *Show updates*, am getting as *The software on this computer is up to date*(see the image below)

[image]

How to solve it ?

Comment: Try the `sudo apt-get update` command line, and post the output in your question

Comment: @Dremor ya i tried that too....

Comment: Can you show us the result?

Comment: I am getting error when I do sudo apt-get update as W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/upubuntu-com/office/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

Answer (score 3, accepted):

open a terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T) and run:

```
sudo apt-add-repository --remove ppa:upubuntu-com/office
```

or with help of `ppa-purge` has to be installed: `sudo apt-get install ppa-purge`

```
sudo ppa-purge ppa:upubuntu-com/office

sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade

sudo apt-get autoremove
```

The reason you're getting this error is because given `PPA` has ended on 12.10 Quantal support, so you need to disable/remove it.

Comment: ppa-purge doesn't work in this case.

Comment: why isn't it? Actually I just listed the possible quicklist commands to solve the issue, seems like it helped the OP ;)

Comment: If there are no trusty packages, than the command doesn't work. That's all.